# Uncaught ReferenceError: defer is not defined

Tags: jquery

```
 <script>


            var addUser = function() {
                var defer = $.Deferred()
                $.ajax("http://localhost/PhpProject1/index.php", {
                    type: "POST",
                    jsonpCallback: 'yes',
                    data: {username: 'test'},
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    dataType: "jsonp"
                });
                 success:(function(data) {
                    defer.resolve(data);
                })

            }
            filtered = defer.then(function(value) {
                return value;
            });
            filtered.done(function(value) {
                console.log(value);
            });
            $("button").on("click", addUser);




        </script>
```

I create above function to retrieve data from jsnop.Here I used Deffered .But when i try this code i get following error.

```
  Uncaught ReferenceError: defer is not defined
```

Comment: defer is a variable local to your addUser function. You can't use it outside...

Comment: how can i solve this can u help me to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you return `defer.promise` from `addUser` you can set up as follows

```
 var addUser = function () {
     var defer = $.Deferred()
     /* ajax and resolve/reject*/
     return defer

 }

 var filtered = addUser().then(function (value) {
     return value;
 });
```

`$.ajax()` also returns a promise. You could do same thing without directly creating a new `$.Deferred`

```
 var addUser = function () {

     return $.ajax({ /* ajax options*/})

 }
```

Comment: i tried it but i gt following error.Uncaught TypeError: Object function () {
                var defer = $.Deferred()
                $.ajax("http://localhost/PhpProject1/index.php", {
                    type: "POST",
                    jsonpCallback: 'yes',
                    data: {username: 'test'},
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    dataType: "jsonp"
                });
                defer.resolve(data);
                return defer.promise

            } has no method 'then' (index):35

Comment: typo in calling `addUser.then`  should be `addUser().then`. I've been working with angular a lot last few months...returning promise slightly diferent...just return `defer`. In your demo you are trying to resolve outside of callbacks of $.ajax.  Here's a working fiddle with real ajax call  http://jsfiddle.net/r3maJ/2/